# Отслеживание переключения между окнами C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Всем привет

Появился вопрос, надо в программе на C++ отследить переключение пользователя между окнами, для того чтобы записать в лог. Например сижу я в браузере, перешел в блокнот, а в логе должна появится запись об этом.

Пробовал гуглить, однако ничего путного не нашел

Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457721/getting-notification-when-active-window-changes

Comment: @Unick Спасибо, языкам заморским не обучен

Comment: Ну так там примеров исходников должно быть достаточно. По сути настраивается hook, который перехватывает сообщения и логирует смену окна.